# SQL Search/Compare Keywords and Orderby similarity

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, full-text-search

I got this challenge to do a related page display based on the keywords of a page.

The application is supposed to display related pages based on the keywords of the current page the user is visiting. It will check the keywords string the page currently has for example it has 3 keywords

```
"Tag,Keyword,Test"
```

It should check other pages in the database for the same keywords. For example the results will be 2 other pages with some of the keywords (not all)

```
PageName | Keyword

 Subpage1| Test,Tag
 Subpage2| Tag
```

I would also like to order them by the relevance, the more keywords is matched the higher the relevance.

Comment: what is your Table Structure ?

Comment: The Keyword column is an nvarchar. All keywords are stored and seperated with a comma.

Comment: I asked for table structure and sample data. help us we help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split](@text varchar(8000), @delimiter varchar(20))
RETURNS @Strings TABLE
(   
  position int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  value varchar(8000)  
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @index int
SET @index = -1

WHILE (LEN(@text) > 0)
  BEGIN 
    SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter , @text) 
    IF (@index = 0) AND (LEN(@text) > 0) 
      BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (@text)
          BREAK 
      END 
    IF (@index > 1) 
      BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (LEFT(@text, @index - 1))  
        SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index)) 
      END 
    ELSE
      SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index))
    END
  RETURN
END
```

Query

```
declare @keyword nvarchar(max) = 'tag,test'

select tabl1.pageName,table1.Keyword,count(keywordname.value) as MatchCount
from table1 inner join 
(select value from fn_Split(@keyword,',')) as keywordname on
table1.keyword like '%'+keywordname.value+'%' 
group by tabl1.pageName,table1.Keyword
order by MatchCount desc
```

Comment: Fantastic, it worked really well! So the function splits the keywords up and checks each of them with an innerjoin query. Thanks a bunch for your help!

Answer (score 0):

YOu can Use `CTE` and `Split` Function using `Cross Apply`

```
;WITH CtePrimary AS(
    SELECT
        LTRIM(RTRIM(s.Data)) AS Keyword,PageName
    FROM PageKeywords k
    CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(k.Primary_Kwd, ",") s
),CteSecondry as (
select Distinct PageName,


 STUFF(
         (SELECT ', ' + convert(varchar(10), t2.keywords, 120)
          FROM CtePrimary t2
          where t1.PageName
         = t2.PageName
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS Keywords 
          ,Count(distinct Keywords) AS KeyCount
from CtePrimary t1 where Keyword In (select Data From dbo.Split(@keywords,',' )) )

select PageName,Keywords from CteSecondry  order by KeyCount desc
```